# Angular code shows in page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm in the process of learning angular. When I execute the code below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-guide-concepts-1-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body >
      <div ng-app ng-init="qty=1;cost=2">
      <b>Invoice:</b>
      <div>
        Quantity: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="qty">
      </div>
      <div>
        Costs: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="cost">
      </div>
      <div>
        <b>Total:</b> {{qty * cost | currency}}
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code that renders shows {{qty * cost | currency}}. Is angular not loading into the browser (chrome) ? I've checked the version of angular and it appears to be ok. Thanks.

Comment: its working. check that angular.min.js loaded :)

Comment: How are you loading this web page in your browser? Your reference to Angular.js is **protocol agnostic** and therefore if on the odd chance you were testing using a local filesystem address it will not work. Prepend the address with `http:` or test using http/https.

Comment: Prepend  http to the local file address?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you angular js is not loaded properly.

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x3uBGzXF7luQ7MscrT8e?p=preview) with your code, this works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app ng-init="qty=1;cost=2">
        <b>Invoice:</b>
        <div>
            Quantity:
            <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="qty">
        </div>
        <div>
            Costs:
            <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="cost">
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>Total:</b> {{qty * cost | currency}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```